# Repeating animation on tap

Tags: ios, swift

I want to rotate a `UIImage`, I have managed to do so with the code below, however when I press the `rotate` button again, the image does not rotate anymore, could someone please explain why?

```
@IBAction func rotate(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        self.shape.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4) * 2)  
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing your shape image view's transform to a new, fixed value. If you tap on it again, the transform already has that value. You set the transform to the same value again, which doesn't change anything.

You need to define an instance variable to keep track of the rotation.

```
var rotation: CGFloat = 0


@IBAction func rotate(sender: UIButton) 
{
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: 
  {
    self.rotation += CGFloat(M_PI_4) * 2 //changed based on Daniel Storm's comment
    self.shape.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)  
  })
}
```

That way, each time your tap the button you'll change the rotation variable from it's previous value to a new value and rotate to that new angle.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.rotation` inside the `block`?

Comment: Thank you ever so much, fantastic explanation with a working result, you're a star! :)

Comment: @DanielStorm Yeah, it did have to be :)

Comment: @DanielStorm, good point. I forget the required `self.` syntax in swift more often than not. I'll go edit my answer.

Comment: @DuncanC I had to add "self" to CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.roation) , not sure if it was needed, but worked just as good :)